# group_by and pivot_wider combination

Tags: r, pivot, group

I have a data frame with three columns:

```
responseid = c(rep("R_cJ6dbDcou", 6), rep("R_a3LWPfGC", 6), rep("R_e3b9tIJo", 6))
year = c(rep(2022, 6), rep(2022, 6), rep(2022, 6)) 
code = c(000, 0500, 0033, 0036, 0102, 0486, 000, 0500, 0032, 
         0039, 0101, 0466, 000, 0500, 0012, 0049, 0111, 0446)
Data = data.frame(responseid , year , code)
```

I would like it to appear with each row as a unique responseid, and each code related to that responseid as a column:

| responseid | code1 | code2 | code3 | code4 | code5 | code6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R_cJ6dbDcou | 000 | 0500 | 0033 | 0036 | 0102 | 0486 |
| R_a3LWPfGC | 000 | 0500 | 0032 | 0039 | 0101 | 0466 |

I've tried grouping by responseid then pivot_wider, but this doesn't seem to work. I end up with each responseid as a column and a list in each cell with the codes for that responseid.

Comment: Duplicate column names are usually a Bad Idea and `pivot_wider` won't create them. Would you be okay if the column names were `code1`, `code2`, etc, or do you have another idea?

Comment: Don't you need years in the output table?

Comment: Yeah, I don't mind what the column names are. I've edited the table to show that. Thanks

Comment: I don't need years in the output table as each responseid is unique across all years.

Comment: Your data has three unique ids. By contrast your expected output has two now.

Comment: Do you need leadings zeros? Is your data numeric (like the toy data) or something else (e.g. character)? Check with `lapply(your_df, class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get from your question whether you expect each column to contain the same code or not.

If yes, the following should work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

responseid = c(rep("123xyz", 6), rep("456abc", 6), rep("789def", 6)) 
year = c(rep(2022, 6), rep(2021, 6), rep(2022, 6))
code = c(000, 0500, 0033, 0036, 0102, 0486, 000, 0500, 0032, 0039, 0101, 0466, 000, 0500, 0012, 0049, 0111, 0446) 
Data = data.frame(responseid , year , code = as.character(code))

Data_name <- Data |> 
  mutate(name = paste("code", code, sep = "_"))

Data_piv <- Data_name |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = responseid,
              values_from = code,
              names_from = name)
```

```
> Data_piv
# A tibble: 3 × 15
  responseid code_0 code_500 code_33 code_36 code_102 code_486 code_32 code_39 code_101 code_466 code_12
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  
1 123xyz     0      500      33      36      102      486      NA      NA      NA       NA       NA     
2 456abc     0      500      NA      NA      NA       NA       32      39      101      466      NA     
3 789def     0      500      NA      NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA       NA       12     
# ℹ 3 more variables: code_49 <chr>, code_111 <chr>, code_446 <chr>
```

Else, this should work:

```
Data_name2 <- Data |> 
  group_by(responseid) |>
  mutate(i = 1:n()) |>
  mutate(name = paste("code", i, sep = "_"))

Data_piv2 <- Data_name2 |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = responseid,
              values_from = code,
              names_from = name)
```

```
> Data_piv2
# A tibble: 3 × 7
# Groups:   responseid [3]
  responseid code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4 code_5 code_6
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 123xyz     0      500    33     36     102    486   
2 456abc     0      500    32     39     101    466   
3 789def     0      500    12     49     111    446   
>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - works with the real data set too. Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Data), 
      responseid ~ paste0("code", Data[, seq_len(.N), by=responseid]$V1), 
      value.var = "code")
# Key: <responseid>
#    responseid code1 code2 code3 code4 code5 code6
#        <char> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     123xyz     0   500    33    36   102   486
# 2:     456abc     0   500    32    39   101   466
# 3:     789def     0   500    12    49   111   446
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works for the example data, but for some reason isn't working for my exact data. I'll amend the dummy data to more closely match the real thing.

Answer (score 1):

### Base

*Updated to meet edited sample data.*

```r
> aggregate(code ~ responseid, data = Data[-2], FUN = I)
   responseid code.1 code.2 code.3 code.4 code.5 code.6
1  R_a3LWPfGC      0    500     32     39    101    466
2 R_cJ6dbDcou      0    500     33     36    102    486
3  R_e3b9tIJo      0    500     12     49    111    446
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr/tidyr` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)                                              
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  select(-year) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number(), .by = responseid) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = code,
              names_from = id,
              names_glue = "{.value}{id}")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   responseid code1 code2 code3 code4 code5 code6
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 123xyz         0   500    33    36   102   486
#> 2 456abc         0   500    32    39   101   466
#> 3 789def         0   500    12    49   111   446
```

##### Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  responseid = c(rep("123xyz", 6), rep("456abc", 6), rep("789def", 6)),
  year = c(rep(2022, 6), rep(2021, 6), rep(2022, 6)),
  code = c(000, 0500, 0033, 0036, 0102, 0486, 000, 0500,
           0032, 0039, 0101, 0466, 000, 0500, 0012, 0049, 0111, 0446) 
)
```